# Convert cents to euro with NumberFormat

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

I have a `long` type value which represents cents in currency. I try to convert it to euros. So, I did the following:

```
long val = 348;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
System.out.println(nf.format(val/100));
```

I thought the above code will print out `3,48 €` but I got `3,00 €`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force floating point arithmetic , you can use a double literal `100.0` or float literal `100.0f` :

```
System.out.println(nf.format(val/100.0));
```

Answer (score 3):

because val/100 is an Integer operation, so the deciaml part is stripped away. For instane
`int i = 1;` `int result = i / 2;` will give you `0`

```
Change to System.out.println(nf.format(((float)val/100)));
```